# A scheduled task running every hour is taking focus away from my games. How do I find which one it is?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, gaming

Every hour a scheduled task runs that opens a command prompt window for a brief moment, this causes any games I'm playing to lose focus and minimize. While I'm not 100% sure it's a scheduled task, it seems likely because it happens at 0 minutes every time.  How do I go about finding which task this is and stopping it from minimizing my games?

I ran `schtasks /query /v /fo CSV` and looked through the results to see which ones had a Next Run Time of the next hour, and there was only a handful of tasks that run hourly:

- \Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\USO_UxBroker_Display
- \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\StartupAppTask
- \Microsoft\Windows\DiskFootprint\StorageSense
- \Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\Scheduled Start (Four instances)

I'm using Windows 10 Pro 1511.

Comment: Disable all of them and re-enable them one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Nirsoft's [ExecutedProgramsList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/executed_programs_list.html) shows logs of what programs have been recently run. It might be able to pinpoint what it is that's running, assuming an exe other than cmd.exe is involved.